# Mixing for Burgers equation in 2+1D

Tags: fluid-dynamics, chaos-theory, non-linear-systems, complex-systems

Let us consider the following (2+1)-dimensional Burgers-like equation:
$$
u_t + (u^2)_x + (u^3)_y=0.
$$
Here the unknown is a function $u= u(t,x,y):(0,\infty) \times \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$.
Is there any physical meaning/relevance to studying the mixing properties of this equation? Are there any results available?

To see what I mean exactly by mixing and what kind of approach/results I'm looking for, see [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physd.2005.07.017) and [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.09909), where linear transport equations are studied.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your first equation? And wouldn't it be more transparent to develop it, in particular the powers?

Comment: @Gert What do you mean by "developing it"?

Comment: Developed it becomes: $u_t+2 u u_x+3 u^2 u_y=0$, looks like a 'fun' thing to solve!

Comment: @Gert I see; sure, we can consider it written like that if you prefer. About the reference, this is a multi-d generalization of the classical Burgers equation $u_t + uu_x = 0$: it is very common in the mathematical literature, but I'm not familiar with the physical literature.

Comment: No, neither am I. Usually *context* can shed some lighton that?

Comment: The full (1+1)-dimesnional Burger's equation has a $u_{xx}$ viscosity term.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed Burger's like equation looks highly advective-dominated and is inviscid in nature. As the inviscid Burgers equation is used for studying flows with shock wave propagation, I would not expect anyone to be interested in quantifying mixing when you have shock waves in your flow. So, from a physical or application perspective (not mathematical), I don't think that this equation would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: do you mean that the formation of singularities is the problem or the lack of viscosity?

Comment: lack of viscosity is what leads to singularities, If by singularities, you refer to the formation of shock waves.\

Comment: I know. But I don't know why physically either of these would be in contrast to mixing

Comment: I didn't mean that they would contrast to mixing. What I meant is that, I have never heard or seen any physical application where you would use a scalar transport equation (used to quantify mixing) along with your proposed equation.

Comment: Maybe, your proposed equation could have mathematical importance, that I do not know.